# How To get String Response using spring controller in ajax and base of that perform action?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

I am fairly new to Ajax. I m trying to call ajax on Logout link, before logout function perform i want to validate any progress running , 
if Spring controller response String value "True" than Link work and if response in string false than Link not work and show alert or Message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function callLogout() {
  var A;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            A=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        A.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(A.readyState==4)
            {
               
                    var data = A.responseText.split('@@');
                    if (data[1].trim() != null && data[1].trim() != '')
                    showNotification('bg-red', data[1].trim(), 'top', 'center', '', ''); // its work like alert using jquery
            }
        }
        A.open('GET','/PMS-1.0.0.3/logout1',true);
        A.send();
 }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:callLogout();"></a>
```

My Controller

@RequestMapping(path = "/logout1" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView logout1(HttpSession session ,EmployeeModel employeeModel, HttpServletRequest req) {

```
    ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
    EmployeeMaster master = null;

    System.out.println("in logout1 Method");

    long emp_id = (long) session.getAttribute("userid");
    ActivityTaskDetails activityTaskDetails = activityTaskRepository.getActiveTaskDetails(emp_id);

    System.out.println("Value get From activity task"+activityTaskDetails);

    if(activityTaskDetails != null){

        map.addAttribute("LogoutValidate","Work in Progress, Youy cant Logout.");
        return new ModelAndView("ajaxpage", map);


    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Else Part session invalidate");

        session.removeAttribute("username");
        session.removeAttribute("userid");
        for (int i=0; i<Global.employeeRightsList.size(); i++) {
            session.removeAttribute("employeeRights_"+Global.employeeRightsList.get(i).getFormMaster().getFormName());
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login");
    }


}
```

```html
Ajax Page 
<c:if test="${LogoutValidate != null}">
@@${LogoutValidate}
</c:if>
```

Comment: Using this code : i get String at response and after trim i can use it for notification or alert